# In IntelliJ, how do i debug a maven test goal?

Tags: testing, maven-2, intellij-idea

Using intellij and maven pom files, how do i debug tests run inside the maven test goal?

When i run them directly in the code, it complains something about profiles missing, which i've ticked inside intellij's Maven Projects.

Comment: [Same question for Integration Tests with Failsafe in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49390110/525036)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about a right click on your goal and "Debug [your goal]" (in your case the test goal)?

[image: debug goal]

Comment: Ahh didn't think of that. Too late on a friday afternoon :D Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you want to use breakpoints, this answer is insufficient. See Hover's answer instead.

Answer (score 233):

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

- When surefire plugin version < 2.14: use `-DforkMode=never`
- When surefire plugin version >= 2.14: use `-DforkCount=0`

In IDEA, open your run/debug configuration, in `Runner` tab, add fork options `-DforkCount=0`

[image]

Comment: That worked for me. I am using the following command to debug the test goal in Idea 10.

Comment: In my multi-module project this was the only option that worked for me from within Intellij.

Comment: With IDEA 11, I found in Maven projects, I had to right click on the test for the module I wanted to test. This created a run/debug configuration. Then edit this new configuration, click on runner tab and add -DforkMode=never in the VM Options. Click ok. Set a break point, then click the debug icon to run the new debug config. A combination of the above, so thanks for the tips.

Comment: @MarkM  Breakpoints are not respected in IJ13 for me using this approach.

Comment: Worth noting newer versions of the surefire plugin (2.14+) use `mvn -DforkCount=0 test`, this is mentioned below in other (confusing) answers, but they could be missed.

Comment: I can't get this to work with Android and Maven. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ with Maven to build for Android. I can't get debugging to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Great. Works for one test class, and also for individual test method(s). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Worked for me with failsafe plugin.

Comment: To all colleagues who say that this solution does not work for them: 
also have a look at "JDK for importer" IntelliJ setting (Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing). Changing from "Use Internal JRE" to your default project JRE can solve the problem.

Comment: I only made it work with -DforkMode=never, and my project uses Surefire/Failsafe 2.22.2...

Answer (score 34):

I execute tests with the following options:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=6666 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
```

... and then connect to Maven with remote debugger.

Comment: Did you manage to get log4j/logging working? I have even included the -Dlog4j.configuration=<path to log4j.properties> but the logging statements are not being printed.

Answer (score 28):

`-DforkMode=never` doesn't work anymore, it is now deprecated in SureFire.

Use `-DforkCount=0` instead when using surefire plugin 2.14+.

Comment: Surefire docs say to use `forkCount` and `reuseForks` instead, so I think the above was meant to say, "Use `-DforkCount=0` instead."  I tried `-DforkCount=0` (`reuseForks` shouldn't matter if there are no forks), but my breakpoint never tripped.  It does trip with `-DforkMode=never` (Maven 3.2.1, IDEA 13.1.2).

Comment: I am seeing the same as @mmindenhall reported. Using maven `3.6.0` and surefire plugin version `2.22.2`, `-DforkCount=0` does not work, while the deprecated `-DforkMode=never` works.

Answer (score 10):

The question has been answered. But just to share my own experience. 
The selected answer did not solve my problem.
My code has multiple modules.

foolshat's reply did bring valuable insight to my problem.

I have two solutions,
1. Using your IDEA, by adding a **VM option** `-DforkMode=never`; Must run it with debug mode.
2. Set up a **remote debugging**, specifying the socket and in this case forkMode is not necessary.

It is just a summary for what I have been through.

Answer (score 2):

`mvn clean verify -DforkCount=0` when using surefire plugin

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Colin Hebert is not working to me neither. But fortunelly I found an easy way to debug the test by doing right click on the green triangle appears next to the test method:

[Java test class example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ETu.png)

I hope thats helps you!

Comment: What I contribute with this comment is a way to debug by openning a windows on IntelliJ. The code of the class is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least now documentation by JetBrains at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-tests-in-maven.html#debug_maven

That is:

1. In intellij, create a remote-jvm debug configuration, select the *service* (important in multi-module project), type `socket`, host `localhost` and set the `port` to something *other* than 5005 (replace below) and just leave the rest to default
2. run

   ```bash
   mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:{port}" -Dtest=YourTestClassName test
   ```
3. Since we're passing `suspend=y`, the surefire process will pause when starting the test VM, at this point you start the remote debug "build" in IntelliJ.

#### Further notes

The JetBrains guide says to run in IDE and that *does* work, but I found it easier to just run in a separate shell.

You *really* want to restrict to a single test class, otherwise you'll have to reconnect for every single class.

Disabling forking had no impact at all for me, at least with Quarkus tests.