# How to properly setup a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 10?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

I know I must be asking something obvious, but I'm new to IDEA and simply can't find it myself.
How do I get my Maven 2 project to look like this in IDEA*:

[image: Taken from question #3784781]

Although I can get my project to run, there are many things I can't do (like debug Maven goals). My project looks like this:

[image: My project]

*Image taken from [question #3784781](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784781/in-intellij-how-do-i-debug-a-maven-test-goal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File | Open Project`, specify **pom.xml** path, in IDEA **Maven Projects** panel you'll see the goals.