# How to debug integration test in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, integration-testing

I have created run configuration in `Maven Projects` for

```
mvn -Dit.test=PredictionWorkflowTest verify
```

which looks like here

[image]

and then set breakpoint inside `PredictionWorkflowTest`. Unfortunately, when I right click this configuration and select to debug it, tests passes as if no breakpoint were set.

How to make breakpoints working?

If I run test by clicking class itself, then breakpoints trigger, but integration conditions don't me (servers not starting).

Comment: You are connecting to the Maven VM when you click Debug for this configuration. Maven starts another VM for your tests and your code is in that VM, therefore the breakpoints do not work. You can use Remote debug to connect to the VM instance you need and debug the tests.

Comment: @CrazyCoder in which circumstances debugger will stop anywhere in this case?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in the code that runs in the Maven VM, like debug the Maven task itself.

Comment: @CrazyCoder actually, you can use `mvn test -DforkMode=never -DforkCount=0 -DreuseForks=false` without remote debug. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper helps with that

Answer (score 21):

### Step 1: Add debug to maven run configuration

You are probably using Maven Failsafe Plugin to run the tests as explained in their [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

If that's the case you need to add `-Dmaven.failsafe.debug` ([documentation here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/debugging.html)) to your maven configuration so it becomes

```
mvn -Dit.test=PredictionWorkflowTest verify -Dmaven.failsafe.debug
```

When you run this maven command, the debugger will be listening at port 5005 by default

### Step 2: Configure remote debugger in IntelliJ

Now in IntelliJ you need to configure a remote debugger configuration on `localhost` and port `5005`

[image: Remote debugger configuration for integration tests]

### Step 3: Debug your app

Finally, run the maven command. Just before testing it will stop and wait for the debugger to start running the tests. The following message will be displayed in the terminal

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then start remote debugger configured in step 2. This should allow you to debug your app on integration tests break-points.